# Is there a way to restrict an Array extension to arrays whose elements are NOT optionals?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

As an example, would it be possible to restrict the accessibility of this extension to arrays whose elements are NOT optional?

```swift
extension Array {
    subscript(safe index: Int) -> Element? {
        return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

The goal would be that

```swift
let array = [String?]()
array[safe: 2]
```

would give a compile error.

Comment: What's wrong with the elements being optionals in `array[safe: 2]`?

Comment: This is very likely an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why do you want to do this in the first place? While it is possible to *abuse* Swift's features and make it show a warning in such a case, this is not how you are intended to write extensions. Why do you not want your `[safe:]` subscript to be available on optional element arrays? Optional element arrays are not safe to access in the first place, just because they have optional elements.

Comment: Please ignore the specifics of the extension I used above, it was just to give a concrete example. But to answer your question, if your array contains optionals and the subscript above returns `nil`, you do not know if it is because you were out of bounds or because there was `nil` at that index. So I want to prevent myself from ever using it on an array where elements can be `nil`.

Comment: Ah, so it was due to a misunderstanding like that. Well, your `subscript` would return a double optional, `String??` in this case, so you *can* actually tell. This holds true in general too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The reason why you wanted to do this seems to just be that you cannot distinguish a nil returned by your subscript, and an actual nil in the array.

Well, you *can*. When you use the subscript on an array of optionals, it would return a *double* optional. e.g. for `[String?]`, it would return `String??`.

Here's an example of determining all 3 cases with a `switch`. You can use `if case` if you just want to check one of them.

```
switch array[safe: 1] {
case .none: // subscript returned nil
    break
case .some(nil): // subscript returned non-nil, but that index in the array contained nil
    break
case .some(let x): // subscript returned non-nil, and that index contained x
    break
}
```

So there is really no need to restrict your subscript to non-`Optional` arrays. Swift is not designed to allow you to do that anyway.

---

Just for a bit of fun though, here's how you can *abuse* Swift's features to make a warning:

```
extension Array {
    subscript<T>(safe index: Int) -> Element? where Element == T {
        return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
    
    @available(swift, deprecated: 1, message: "Do not use this on arrays of optionals!")
    subscript<T>(safe index: Int) -> Element? where Element == T? {
        return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

I added an extra `subscript` that only works on arrays of optionals, but it is marked deprecated since Swift 1 (lol). I added an extra type parameter to the other overload too, so that overload resolution would consider them equally. Otherwise it would always prefer the one with fewer type parameters - we want it to decide based on the generic constraints instead.

Now when you do `array[safe: 1]`, overload resolution chooses the one marked deprecated, and produces a warning.

Comment: Thank you, how interesting! Given what you explain, we might end up not using the extension at all, as we wouldn't be able to "enforce" good programming (= using a switch statement on the double optional) by showing an error or warning. So there unfortunately doesn't seem to be a way to do what we need, as "Swift is not designed to allow you to do that anyway". Out of curiosity, would you happen to know the reasoning behind Swift allowing restricting an extension to arrays whose elements are optionals, but not allowing restricting the extension to arrays whose elements are not optionals?

Comment: @Kqtr I don't know the true reason, but I don't think such a feature is very cost-effective. It doesn't offer too much of a benefit (I think your situation is pretty rare), and is not trivial to implement. There might also be conflicts with other features that I don't know about.

Comment: It isn't that Swift doesn't allow you to restrict an extension to "not optional" but rather that it doesn't allow you to restrict extensions to "not anything". Ie. you can't restrict an extension to the element being "not String" but you can restrict it to where the element is String. Since Optional is just a protocol, you can apply the restriction.  As Sweeper said I doubt that an inversion of restriction has even occurred to anyone but you could always propose it via Swift Evolution.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you for taking the time to explain. Wish you the best!